# 2checkout REST API 6.0 Empty Item in response from GET subscription

Tags: 2checkout

I'm using 2checkout Rest API 6.0
https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/2Checkout-API/api-rest_documentation/6.0-oas3#/Subscription/get_subscriptions_

But when executing a GET /subscription/ call, the response is an empty Item
[https://api.2checkout.com/rest/6.0/subscriptions/?CustomerEmail='](https://api.2checkout.com/rest/6.0/subscriptions/?CustomerEmail=%27) + encoded_email

Response:

> {'Items': [], 'Pagination': {'Page': 1, 'Limit': 10, 'Count': 0}}

It seems, the user exist (no error message), I can see the "Subscription reference" number for the email when loggin in to 2checkout web admin. What am I doing wrong?